# Limits, need help

Tags: limits

I need to calculate the following:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\bigg(\frac{2+\sin(3x)-2\cos(2x)}{2+\sin(3x)-2\cos(3x)}\bigg)^\frac{3}{x}$$

So I was trying to solve it but I still have an uncertainty
[Lim x->0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppvPs.jpg)

Comment: Question not clear

Comment: @anirudh, fixed it

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. The downvotes are because you posted a link to an image rather than a statement of the question, and didn't show how far you got yourself and where you were stuck. Even though you did get an answer. please post questions properly from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that your term can be written in the form
$$e^{\frac{3}{x}\ln\left(\frac{2+\sin(3x)-2\cos(2x)}{2+\sin(3x)-2\cos(3x)}\right)}$$